# How to get the result of mt_rand in a session

Tags: php, session, random

I want my website to have a random background every time it is refreshed, but after someone logs in, I want this background to stay the same the rest of the session. I have found the following code for the random background:

```
<?php    
$bg = array('bg-01.jpg', 'bg-02.jpg', 'bg-03.jpg', 'bg-04.jpg', 'bg-05.jpg', 'bg-06.jpg', 'bg-07.jpg', 'bg-08.jpg', 'bg-09.jpg', 'bg-10.jpg', 'bg-11.jpg', 'bg-12.jpg', 'bg-13.jpg');

$n = mt_rand(0, count($bg)-1);
  $selectedBg = "$bg[$n]";     
?>
```

For your interest: this is how I made sure the selected bg was truly the background of the page (this is put in the `<head>` section):

```
<style type="text/css">
body{
background: url(../afbeeldingen/<?php echo $selectedBg; ?>) ; background-size: 100%; background-attachment: fixed;
}
</style>
```

This works fine. but now I want to put the output in a session. At first i thought this would work:

```
$_SESSION['background']= "$selectedBg";
```

This does put a random number in a session but that number is not the same as outputted with the `mt_rand` before. I have also been struggling with the following JavaScript

```
<script>
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
</script>
```

but I could not match the output to $bg array presented before.
I am still a beginner in PHP.

Comment: Why are you using quotes? `$selectedBg = "$bg[$n]";` and `$_SESSION['background']= "$selectedBg";`

Comment: And you should be testing to see if the session value is set before generating your random number and resetting the background

Comment: Are you evaluating if `$_SESSION['background']` contains a value before generating a random value?

Comment: You need to check the session before you generate a new bg. Otherwise you will end up with always a new bg in the session.

Comment: @MarkBaker When I put them away I get literally no image as background

Comment: `$selectedBg = $bg[$n];` should work perfectly well, giving you a background value; likewise `$_SESSION['background']= $selectedBg;`

Comment: I have put `unset ($_SESSION['achtergrond']);` at the top of my page

Answer (score 3):

Do it like this,

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])){
    $selectedBg = "bg-".rand(1, 13).".jpg";
    $_SESSION['background'] = $selectedBg;
    echo $_SESSION['background'];
}else{
    echo $_SESSION['background'];
}
```

When the guest is here, they will get a new background and you can use `rand()` function rather than the array you have, it will help you, 
And second you check if the user is logged in you give them the last background they got, if not,  change the background.

I hope this helps you,

Comment: Well, it doesn't solve my problem. I should've told that the page you land on when you go to my page is directly the login page. When you log in you still land on a page with another background. I think I will implant something that you will have a random background on the homepage and that users can pick a background they like and set that as the standard for that user. Still thank you for your answer.

Comment: You're welcome, yeah you can let the user select and store it in database. but `$_SESSION['background']` pass to all pages in the website, so i think there must be no problems.